# Forward/Redirect request of Elastic IP to Heroku

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, redirect, forwarding, heroku

I have a hardware with a Elastic IP(Amazon) hardcoded in the firmware(I know, it was a dumb idea, but wasnt my idea). Now I have to forward a request of this EIP(Elastic IP) to a Heroku instance. I think I can do that with a combination of amazon products maybe Network interface, EIP, Route 53, but I have no clue how to do that,can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think I can do that with a combination of amazon products maybe
>   Network interface, EIP, Route 53, but I have no clue how to do
>   that,can anyone help?

No, you won't be able to attach your EIP to Heroku or otherwise route your traffic there. Even if there was a practical way to do this, the IPs used by Heroku would certainly be subject to change just like they are with ELB.

If you really need to use Heroku then your only option is a reverse proxy, for example [using NGINX](http://nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/). You'll have to run that on an EC2 instance.